# If $T$ is linear transformation from $P_3(\mathbb{R})\to P_3(\mathbb{R})$ such that $T(P(x))=4x+7$, then Nullity(T) is

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T$ is linear transformation from $P_3(\mathbb{R})\to P_3(\mathbb{R})$ such that $T(P(x))=4x+7$, then Nullity(T) is :

(A) 3, (B) 2, (C) 1, (D) 0

This question was asked in a exam. I think this is wrong question as $T$ is not linear. It is a constant function. Am I wright?

Comment: Right. Perhaps there is a typo.

Comment: You’re right that the transformation given isn’t linear, since for instance letting $p(x)$ be any polynomial we’d like, $T(0 \cdot p) = T(\textbf{0}) = 4x + 7$ but $0 \cdot T(p) = \textbf{0}.$ I would say I find it likely that they meant $T(p) = 4p + 7$ but that’s also notably not a linear transformation for similar reasons. So I’m not sure if it’s a typo or if they just made a mistake but yes, the problem does contradict itself.

Comment: maybe they meant $T(p(x)) = p(4x+7)$? That's linear, and there's a correct answer amongst the 4 given.